# Error while connecting to MySQL 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query when iam trying to connect to my remote mysql server

Tags: python, mysql

Iam trying to connect my python application to my remote mysql server but iam facing issues like Error while connecting to MySQL 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query.

I even tried to increase timeout but still iam getting same issue.

Could any one suggest me solution to connect to remote server

connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='remote-server-ip',user='admin',password='server-password',port=3306)

print(connection)

iam getting this error

mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Comment: Can you show us the way you are trying to connect and also the complete unchanged error message please

Comment: connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                         database='Electronics',
                                         user='pynative',
                                         password='pynative@#29')

Comment: Does it fail there or when you try and run a query?

Comment: it fails in connection step itself

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, provide more information about your code and connection strings (edit your answer to insert that information). Thanks